# Cypress 10+ 'Could not resolve "fs"' and 'Could not resolve "crypto"' after transfering plugins from cypress/plugins/index.js to cypress.config.ts

Tags: typescript, plugins, cypress, node-modules

I updated to Cypress 10+. I try to transfer plugin configuration from cypress/plugins/index.js to cypress.config.ts . I read new documentation for every plugin that I used and preconfigure it. However, I met some strange problem that I can't find a solution to anywhere on the internet.

Here are my cypress.config.ts, but I think the exact problem doesn't come from the migration.

```
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";
// import { setupMaster } from "cluster";
// Call cy-verify-downloads plugin library.
const { verifyDownloadTasks } = require('cy-verify-downloads');

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: '7emkc5',
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'cypress/report/mochawesome-report',
    overwrite: false,
    html: true,
    json: true,
    timestamp: 'dd-mm-yyyy_HH-MM-ss',
  },
  // theme: 'dark',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    async setupNodeEvents(on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );

      // This is required to reading data from the excel file.
      const xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
      const fs = require('fs'); // for file
      const path = require('path'); // for file path
      on('task', {
        parseXlsx({ filePath }) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
              const jsonData = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
              resolve(jsonData);
            } catch (e) {
              reject(e);
            }
          });
        }
      });
      const readXlsx = require('./cypress/support/DataDrivenTestingWithExcel/read-xlsx')
      module.exports = (on, config) => {
        on('task', {
          'readXlsx': readXlsx.read
        })
      }

      // Call cy-verify-downloads plugin.
      on('task', verifyDownloadTasks);

      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,feature}',
    // Time, in milliseconds, to wait for page transition events or cy.visit(), cy.go(), cy.reload() commands to fire their page load events. Network requests are limited by the underlying operating system, and may still time out if this value is increased.
    pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  },
})
```

This is the error that I receive when I try to execute some random Cypress test. I am not sure what is wrong. I try to install "fs" manually but with no positive result. I found that "crypto" is deprecated and included in the node by default.
node_modules/cy-verify-downloads/src/index.js:2:44: ERROR: Could not resolve "fs"
node_modules/cy-verify-downloads/src/index.js:3:32: ERROR: Could not resolve "crypto"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was. I reversed the changes and made the migration again. Maybe I didn't do something correctly. I think I did not change the version of the cy-verify-downloads plugin, but I made the configuration for the last version.

Comment: so, did you figure this out? I have the exact issue.